# Get Formulas In Terms of their Precedents

Tags: excel

This is more of a conceptual question, I'm certainly not asking for a subroutine to be written for me, but I have a curious issue in Excel.  I need to extract 3500+ formulas from an Excel workbook.  Each formula that I need to extract references many other cells (some on the same worksheet, some on other worksheets), and tracing dependents they go as deep as 14 levels in some instances.  I need to re-write these formulas in terms of their lowest level precedents, if that makes sense.

As an example, consider that cell E1 has the formula `=A1+C1` but cell A1 has the formula `A5*A6` and cell C1 has the formula `=C5`.  What I need to return is the formula in terms of the 2nd (or lowest) level so that I get `=A5*A6 + C5` as the result.  Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

I have been working with some code, specifically using the `Navigate Arrow` method.  I am currently looking through code I found from [here](http://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/) which returns all levels and precedents for a range, but I haven't been able to alter it to my needs.

Conceptually speaking, can anyone help me proceed with **getting Excel formulas in terms of their lowest-level precedents**?

Comment: That's non-trivial except in simple cases: consider Named Ranges and Named Formulas, Array Formulas, INDIRECT, OFFSET, GETPIVOTDATA, resolving forward refrences etc etc: Are you sure you want to duplicate the Excel calculation engine?

Comment: I certainly don't want to, I am just required to.  Most of the formulas are simple addition and subtraction though, which is more favorable.  What I may have to do is develop something for simple cases, which is many of them, and then handle the rest myself.